From Polar Decomposition of $T$ to know normality of the operator of $T$
There is a statement (from Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras. Volume II: Advanced Theory, by Richard V. Kadison) that $T$ is a normal operator if and only if its decomposition $T=UH$ (where $U$ is the partial isometry and $H$ is the positive operator) satisfy $UH=HU$.

Theorem 6.1.2(Polar decomposition) If $T$ is a bounded operator on the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, there is $a$ partial isometry $V$ with initial space the closure $r(T^*)$ of the range of $T^*$ and final space $r(T)$ such that $T=V(T^*T)^{1/2}=$ $(TT^*)^{1/2}V$. If $T =WH$ with $H$ positive and $W$ a partial isometry whose initial space is $r(H)$, then $H=(T^*T)^{1/2}$ and $W=V$.


If $T$ is normal, $(T^*T)^{1/2}=(TT^*)^{1/2}(=H)$.Thus $UH=T=HU$ (from Theorem 6.1.2). Conversely, from uniqueness of the polar decomposition (“left”and“right”),if $UH=HU$,$(T^*T)^{1/2}=(TT^*)^{1/2}$ and $T^*T=TT^*$.

My question: Can we get $(T^*T)^{1/2}=(TT^*)^{1/2}$
from uniqueness of the (right) polar decomposition? Though we have $(T^*T)^{1/2}U=(TT^*)^{1/2}U$, why can we ensure the range of $U$ coincides $\ker(H)^\perp$? Here I think the uniqueness of the (right) polar decomposition means:
If $T =HW$ with $H$ positive and $W$ a partial isometry whose final space is $\ker(H)^\perp$, then $H=(TT^*)^{1/2}$ and $W=V$.

Edit:
This question was mentioned in the second paragraph of Preface to the second printing. The asseration is: If $T$ has left polar decomposition $UH$ and right polar decomposition $HU$ (so that, of course, $UH=HU$), then $T$ is normal.
This is correct: uniqueness of left (resp. right) polar decomposition ensures that $H=(T^{\ast}T)^{1/2}$(resp. $H=(TT^\ast)^{1/2}$). Thus $TT^\ast=T^{\ast}T$.

The claim is false. Say, $T$ is the right-shift operator on $\ell^2$. Then its polar decomposition is $T = T \cdot \text{Id}_{\ell^2}$. Of course, $T \cdot \text{Id}_{\ell^2} = \text{Id}_{\ell^2} \cdot T$, but $T$ is not normal.
